# Download all high chart output from R shiny

Tags: r, highcharts

I have a set of charts and several tables on a Shiny pages. What would be the best way to create a download button to allow user download all of them to one file (i.e pdf). I tried `grid.arrange` but I am not sure how to convert the highchart objects to grobs objects.

Samples of outputs are below:

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

data(citytemp)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(

        column(width = 8,
           highchartOutput("hcontainer1",height = "500px")),
        column(width = 8,
                  highchartOutput("hcontainer2",height = "500px")),
        column(width = 8,
               highchartOutput("hcontainer3",height = "500px")),
        column(width = 12,dataTableOutput("table"))
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {

  output$hcontainer1 <- renderHighchart({
    hc <- highcharts_demo() %>%
      hc_rm_series("Berlin") %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "line")
    hc
  })

  output$hcontainer2 <- renderHighchart({
    hc <- highcharts_demo() %>%
      hc_rm_series("Berlin") %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "bar")
    hc
  })

  output$hcontainer3 <- renderHighchart({
    hc <- highcharts_demo() %>%
      hc_rm_series("Berlin") %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "column")
    hc
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    dt <- data.frame(iris[1:10,])
    dt
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try putting a download button at each column. I am unable to install `highcharter` now so I didn't fully test the code. Let me know if you are having issues -

```
column(width = 8,
           highchartOutput("hcontainer1",height = "500px"), downloadButton("downloadplot1", label = "Download"))
```

Write a separate function for generating the plot -

```
gen_plot <- function(series_name, chart_type){
    hc <- highcharts_demo() %>%
      hc_rm_series(series_name) %>% 
      hc_chart(type = chart_type)
    hc
}
```

Now in `server` -

```
output$downloadplot1 <- downloadHandler(filename ="1.png",
                                         content = function(file) {
                                           png(file, width=800, height=800)
                                           gen_plot("Berlin", "line")
                                           dev.off()
                                         },
                                         contentType = "image/png")
```

Comment: I think this would only download one chart. I would like to download all charts and tables output into one file.

Comment: @southwind anyway you can expand on this. You can have one download button that builds all plots and saves everything, or you have to do this for each plot